# SharePoint Designer 2010 Doesn't Work

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I can't open my site with SharePoint Designer 2010.

I get the well known message:

```
The Web server at "http://tfs" does not appear to have Microsoft SharePoint Foundation installed.
```

I've spent a good deal of time researching and troubleshooting already and have checked the following:

- Enable Client Integration is set to Yes for the web application
- All checkboxes are checked under the site collection's SharePoint Designer Settings
- Connecting to the Central Administration website from SD works no problem
- I can browse the site in the SD Open Site window, but when I actually click open, I get the error
- Logged in and tried as the SharePoint service account, the domain admin account, my account which is an admin, and the site collection admin account
- Creating a new site collection in the same web application and trying to connect to it yields the same error
- Compared all the site settings in IIS Manager between the Central Admin site and the web application running on port 80

How can I get this basic SharePoint functionality working (not that anything in SharePoint is basic from an administrative sense...)?

Comment: Have you tried using the fqdn? `http://tfs[.domain.tld]`

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? We have the same issue and have tried all of the above suggested steps and the ones in the ms link.

Comment: SharePoint Designer is really screwed up in the way it connects to SharePoint (it uses WebDav). WebDav doesn't operate correctly unless there is a top level site collection. I created a top level site collection and then was able to connect to my sub-site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a KB Article available on Microsoft's site. It looks like you have not completed all steps in resolution that it suggests.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981223

Comment: This did not fix the problem. Is there other suggestions?